# PHP login script not working with page avaible errors

Tags: php, message

My login script displays an error message after pressing the `reg` button, and I can only get one echo message back.

**Edit one**

Is it meaningful to use `elseif` or should i use `if ... else ...`?

**Edit two**

After the program has finished, how can I display all available errors the program encountered under the input boxes?

---

**PHP**

```
    <?php
if($_POST['reg'] == "Registrieren"){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username  = $_POST['user']; 
    $password  = $_POST['pw'];
    $passwordrep = $_POST['pwrep'];

    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $username  = stripslashes($username); 
    $password  = stripslashes($password);
    $passwordrep = stripslashes($passwordrep);

    /*if(isset($_SESSION['log']) OR $_SESSION['log'] == 1){
        $error['already_online'] = 1;
        $error['main'] = 1;
    }else*/if(empty($username)){
        $error['username_empty'] = 1;
        $error['main'] = 1;
    }else{
        if(empty($email)){
            $error['email_empty'] = 1;
            $error['main'] = 1;
        }else{
            if(empty($password) OR empty($passwordrep)){
                $error['passwords_empty'] = 1;
                $error['main'] = 1;
            }else{
                if($password == $passwordrep){
                    $error['password_confirm'] = 1;
                    $error['main'] = 1;
                }else{
                    if(strlen($username) < 6 OR strlen($username) > 64){
                        $error['username_too_short'] = 1;
                        $error['main'] = 1;
                    }else{
                        if(strlen($password) < 8 OR strlen($passwordrep) < 8){
                            $error['password_too_short'] = 1;
                            $error['main'] = 1;
                        }else{
                            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                                $error['email_invalid'] = 1;
                                $error['main'] = 1;
                            }else{
                                if(!preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{2,64}$/i', $username)){
                                    $error['username_invalid'] = 1;
                                    $error['main'] = 1;
                                }else{
                                    if($error['main'] = 0){
                                    include_once("config/db_config.php");

                                    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);
                                    $username  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username); 
                                    $password  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
                                    $passwordrep = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $passwordrep);

                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hp_user WHERE username = '$username'";
                                    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($msg_signup["signup_no_connection_aviable"]);
                                    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                                    if($row == 1){
                                        $error['username_exists'] = 1;
                                        $error['main'] = 1;
                                    }else{
                                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM hp_user WHERE email = '$email'";
                                        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($msg_signup["signup_no_connection_aviable"]);
                                        $row = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
                                        if($row == 1){
                                            $error['email_exists'] = 1;
                                            $error['main'] = 1;
                                        }else{
                                            $_SESSION['log'] = 1;
                                            $_SESSION['user'] = $query->username;
                                            $_SESSION['email'] = $query->email;
                                            $add = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `agptest`.`hp_user` (`ID`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `date`, `locked`, `permission`) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$email', '$passwordrep', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '0', '1');"); 
                                            $error['main'] = 0;
                                            mysqli_close();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php
if ($error['main'] == "0") {
    header("Location: http://www.allgameplay.de/?site=default");
}else{
    echo "<h1>Registrierung</h1>";
    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"index.php\">\n";
    echo "Benutzername:<br><input name=\"user\" type=\"text\" size=\"30\"><br>";
    if($error['username_empty'] == 1){
        echo $msg_signup['signup_user_empty'];
    }
    if($error['username_too_short'] == 1){
        echo $msg_signup['signup_user_too_short'];
    }
    if($error['username_invalid'] == 1){
        echo "Dein Benutzername ist ungültig!";
    }
    echo "<br>E-Mail Adresse:<br><input name=\"email\" type=\"text\" size=\"30\"><br>";
    if($error['email_empty'] == 1){
        echo "Du hast keine E-Mail Adresse angegeben!";
    }
    if($error['email_invalid'] == 1){
        echo "Dies ist keine richtige E-Mail Adresse!";
    }
    echo "<br>Passwort:<br><input name=\"pw\" type=\"password\" size=\"30\"><br>";
    if($error['passwords_empty'] == 1){
        echo "Du hast kein Passwort angegeben!";
    }
    echo "<br>Passwort wiederholen:<br><input name=\"pwrep\" type=\"password\" size=\"30\"><br>";
    if($error['passwords_empty'] == 1){
        echo "Du hast kein Passwort angegeben!";
    }
    if($error['password_confirm'] == 1){
        echo "Die Passw&ouml;rter stimmen nicht überein!";
    }
    echo "<br><input type=\"submit\" name=\"reg\" value=\"Registrieren\"><br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the error message is?

Comment: This "error-message(s)" are the own declared messages. They won't displayed under the form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit One

Yes, you should use elseif, it makes your code look cleaner.

Edit Two

You can use GET method to return your errors with switch statement and foreach loops.

Either that or you can use jQuery to check for errors and configure it without PHP.

[jQuery Validation Implementation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

**EDIT:**

```
$error = array('abc','def', 'ghi');
foreach ($error as $i) {
    switch ($i) {
        case "abc":
            echo $i;
        case "def":
            echo $i;
        case "ghi":
            echo $i;
        default:
            echo "No case found!";
    }
}
```

I hope this clears your doubt on foreach loops.

Comment: How can i do this exactly with an `foreach` loop? Can you please post a very short example?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
if($password == $passwordrep)
```

to

```
if($password != $passwordrep)
```

and you need to declare error array before if($_POST['reg'] == "Registrieren")